# ActivityOptions onClickListener Image not transitioning

Tags: android

I am trying to transition the same image to another activity, however when clicking on my item, it doesn't transition or in fact do anything.

Here is my attempt:

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imgThumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
        imgThumbnail.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvNature = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nature);
        placeholder = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.placeholder);


        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View itemView) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), RestaurantDetails.class);
                ActivityOptions activityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) itemView.getContext(), imgThumbnail, "image");
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: You just created your Intent, you need to use it now with startActivity(intent);

Comment: added this "activity.startActivity(intent);"

but now giving a new error - " java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Activity.startActivity(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference"